# use select() to send signal to child process

Tags: process, ocaml, signals, fork

I am trying to send some signals (e.g. SIGSTOP, SIGUSR1) from the parent process based on different user inputs to the child process. The parent process keeps waiting for user input and sends the corresponding signals to the child. If there is no user input, the child does its own job.

I put my Ocaml code here but I am not sure I used the right way to do it.
I am writing in OCaml but solutions in other languages (e.g. C/Python) are also welcome.

```
let cr, pw = Unix.pipe () in
let pr, cw = Unix.pipe () in

match Unix.fork () with
| 0 -> (* child *)
    Unix.close pr;
    Unix.close pw;
    Unix.dup2 cw Unix.stdout;
    Unix.execvp ... (* execute something *)
| pid -> (* parent *)
    Unix.close cr;
    Unix.close cw;
    Unix.dup2 pr Unix.stdin;
    while true do
        try
            match Unix.select [pr] [] [] 0.1 with
            | ([], [], []) -> (* no user input *)
              (* I assume it should do next iteration and wait for next user input *)
              raise Exit
            | (_, _, _) -> (* some user input *)
              let i = read_int () in
              (* send signal to the child process *)
              if i = 1 then Unix.kill pid Sys.sigstop
              else if i = 2 then Unix.kill pid Sys.sigusr1;
        with Exit -> ()
    done
```

Meanwhile, if I would like to define some signals (using SIGUSR1), how and where should I do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not very clear what you're trying to do. Here are some comments on the code you show.

The parent process seems to be reading a pipe that it has itself created (`pr`). But you say the parent process is waiting for user input. User input isn't going to show up in a pipe that you create yourself.

Almost always you look for user input by reading the standard input, `Unix.stdin`.

The code creates another pipe that appears to be intended for the use of the child process, but there are no arrangements for the file descriptors of the pipe to be accessed by the child. The child will instead read the standard input of the parent and write to the parent's standard output.

Your code calls `select` with a timeout of 0.1 seconds. This means the call will return 10 times per second whether there is any input in the pipe or not. Every time it returns it will write a newline. So the output will be a stream of newlines appearing at the rate of around 10 per second.

You say you want to define signals, but it's not at all clear what this means. If you mean you want to define signal *handlers* for the child, this isn't possible in the code you show. Handlers of signals are not preserved across a call to `Unix.execvp`. If you think about it, this is the only way things could work, since the `execvp` call obliterates all the code in the parent process and replaces it with code from some other executable file.

It is not difficult to fork a child and then send it signals. But it's not clear what you're trying to do with the pipes and with the select. And it's not clear what you expect the signals to do in the child process. If you explain these, it would be easier to give a more detailed answer.

**Update**

In general, it's not a good idea to modify code that you've posted to StackOverflow (other than to fix typos), because the previous comments and answers no longer make sense with the new code. It's better to post updated code.

Your new code looks more like you're trying to read input *from the child* through a pipe. This is more sensible, but then it is not what I would call "user input."

You haven't specified where the child's input is supposed to come from, but I suspect you are planning to send input through the other pipe.

If so, this is a notoriously unreliable setup due to buffering between the child process and its pipes. If you haven't written the code for the child process yourself, there's no way to be sure it will read the proper sized data from the read pipe and flush its output to the write pipe at appropriate times. The usual result is that things immediately stall and make no progress.

If you are writing the code for the child process, you need to make sure it reads data in sizes that are being written by the parent. If the child asks for more data than this, it will block. If the parent is waiting for the answer to appear in its read pipe, you will have deadlock (which is the usual result unless you're very careful).

You also need to make sure the child flushes its output any time it is ready to be read by the parent process. And you also need to flush the output of the parent process any time you want it to be read by the child process. (And the parent has to write data in the sizes that are expected by the child.)

You haven't explained what you're trying to do with signals, so I can't help with that. It doesn't make much sense (to me) to read integer values written by the child process and send signals to the child process in response.

Here is some code that works. It doesn't do anything with signals, because I don't understand what you're trying to do. But it sets up the pipes properly and sends some fixed-length lines of text through the child process. The child process just changes all the characters to upper case.

```
let cr, pw = Unix.pipe ()
let pr, cw = Unix.pipe ()

let () =
match Unix.fork () with
| 0 -> (* Child process *)
  Unix.close pr;
  Unix.close pw;
  Unix.dup2 cr Unix.stdin;
  Unix.dup2 cw Unix.stdout;
  Unix.close cr;
  Unix.close cw;
  let rec loop () =
    match really_input_string stdin 6 with
    | line ->
      let ucline = String.uppercase_ascii line in
      output_string stdout ucline;
      flush stdout;
      loop ()
    | exception End_of_file -> exit 0
  in
  loop ()
| pid ->
  (* Parent process *)
  Unix.close cr;
  Unix.close cw;
  Unix.dup2 pr Unix.stdin;
  Unix.close pr;
  List.iter (fun s ->
    let slen = String.length s in
    ignore (Unix.write_substring pw s 0 slen);
    let (rds, _, _) =
      Unix.select [Unix.stdin] [] [] (-1.0)
    in
    if rds <> [] then
      match really_input_string stdin 6 with
      | line -> output_string stdout line
      | exception End_of_file ->
        print_endline "unexpected EOF"
    )
    ["line1\n"; "again\n"];
  Unix.close pw;
  exit 0
```

When I run it I see this:

```
$ ocaml unix.cma m.cmo
LINE1
AGAIN
```

If you change either of the test lines to be shorter than 6 bytes, you'll see the deadlock that usually happens when people try to set up this dual-pipe scheme.

Your code for sending signals looks OK, but I don't know what you expect to happen when you send one.

Comment: I updated some of my code. Hope that makes things more clear. Let me know if there are still something wrong about user interaction. As for define signals, what you mean is I shouldn't directly call `execvp`, instead I should use the actual code and catch the signal `SIGUSR1` during execution?